# Does OFDMA replace CSMA/CA for supported clients in 802.11ax?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I know that up until 802.11ax, Wi-Fi used OFDM for multiplexing and CSMA/CA for access.

In Wi-Fi 6, OFDMA is used for access if the client supports it. But is CSMA/CA still used together with OFDMA, is it necessary? I know OFDMA assigns RUs and time slots to clients, so they know when to transmit. Does this mean they don't have to listen for opportunities to transmit anymore?

Comment: This is wireless, so Collison detection is always required.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that up until 802.11ax, Wi-Fi used OFDM for multiplexing and CSMA/CA for access.

Wait, we probably need to differentiate between two separate meanings of "multiplexing" here.

OFDM's "M" is for Multiplexing, but in that context, it's only referring to packing multiple subcarriers into a single channel. It's just another way for a device to achieve higher throughput when transmitting a packet.

OFDM's multiplexing is NOT a way to allow multiple devices to share a transmission medium (radio channel). So it's not a "Multiple Access" (*MA) kind of multiplexing.

802.11, since the beginning (1997), has primarily used TDMA (specifically CSMA/CA) for multiple access. So 802.11-1997, 802.11b, 802.11a, and 802.11g, 802.11n, and 802.11ac all used CSMA/CA for multiple access. Even 802.11ax primarily uses CSMA/CA for multiple access. AX adds **options**, that so far are **rarely used**, to use OFDMA and uplink MU-MIMO for multiple access, but probably 99.9% of AX transmissions still use CSMA/CA for multiple access to the medium to this day.

Original 802.11-1997 used single-carrier DBPSK and DQPSK modulation (no OFDM) to reach signaling speeds of 1 and 2Mbps respectively. 802.11b, which hit the market in 1999 as Apple AirPort, and later was the first version of 802.11 to be called Wi-Fi, used single carrier CCK modulation to add 5.5Mbps and 11Mbps signaling rates.

802.11a, which enabled operation in the 5GHz band and hit the market around 2002, introduced OFDM multicarrier modulation to reach signaling speeds of 54Mbps. 802.11g, which hit the market around 2003, copied 802.11a's 54Mbps OFDM multicarrier modulation but brought it to the 2.4GHz band, which was more popular due to the installed base of 2.4GHz 802.11b Wi-Fi.

I think it's best to think of OFDM almost like a fancy modulation scheme. It's not a multiple-access scheme. It just speeds up each packet transmission, but packets are still transmitted one a time, and the devices share the medium via CSMA/CA. They still take turns transmitting.

In AX (802.11ax, marketed as "Wi-Fi 6"), in the real world, CSMA/CA still dominates. OFDMA is an option that you can't take advantage of until your AP and at least two clients of the AP support it. And not all AX-capable clients support OFDMA, since it is optional. I know that the first iPhone models to support AX didn't support OFDMA. I don't know if that has changed, but I wouldn't be surprised if it hasn't. I suspect many AX implementations out there don't have their OFDMA support enabled yet, if ever.

So all AX devices still support CSMA/CA, and in fact it is still the predominant multiple access scheme in use, even in networks where every device supports AX.

Even if we someday reach a future where all the Wi-Fi devices you ever see on your network support OFDMA, the way OFDMA operation is currently designed for Wi-Fi still uses CSMA/CA between OFDMA TXOPs. That is, the AP uses CSMA/CA to gain access to the medium to start a packet transmission operation, and then in the preamble it tells OFDMA devices which RU's (blocks of subcarriers; segments of the channel width) to use for this packet transmission, and then those clients are each able to transmit a packet simultaneously, and then when the last client finishes transmitting its packet, the medium goes back into CSMA/CA mode until the AP schedules another OFDMA TXOP.

Comment: @qbccd 802.11-1997 (1, 2 Mbps) and 802.11b (5.5, 11 Mbps, in late 1999) all used single-carrier modulation. I misspoke when I said it was introduced with N. It was actually introduced with A/G in the 2002/2003. The first 5 years of 802.11, including the technology (802.11b) that was first popularized in the mass market as "Apple AirPort" and then "Wi-Fi", was single-carrier, no OFDM.

Comment: Thanks, this clarified a lot for me. Just one thing, I'm pretty sure all versions of 802.11 starting in 1997 have used OFDM for multiplexing. It's just that ax implemented the OFDMA option for access, before that it was only CSMA/CA. But yes it makes sense that CSMA/CA is baked into the 802.11 ax implementation of OFDMA. In unlicensed spectrum, you always have to have it it seems, you can't use OFDMA alone like you can with cellular. But it's still OFDMA, just a different implementation.

Comment: Ah you are right, it started with 802.11a. The previous 2 used spread spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this:
[https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/wireless/what-is-ofdma.html#~q-a](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/wireless/what-is-ofdma.html#%7Eq-a)

I conclude that OFDM and OFDMA are about the 312.5-kHz subcarriers **ONLY** which would imply that CSMA/CA still is present on the upper (channel) level.